# How to Automate mainframe through Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, mainframe

How do I automate main frame application with use of Selenium, which pulgin should i use?
Does sequili works on mainframe?
Also I have to automate AS400.
Does anyone has useful content on github?

Comment: Most mainframe shops already have a job scheduler.  Why would you want to add another?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: See also https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/32633/automation-testing-of-mainframe-application-using-selenium

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Selenium to automate mainframe application. Selenium is just to automate web applications. Please look into Jagacy, which is a java library with which you can automate mainframe applications. For more info please go through the below website,

https://dzone.com/articles/automated-acceptance-testing-for-mainframe-with-cu

Thanks & Regards,

Vinod Baradwaj

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can automate mainframe using selenium as  Selenium is intended only for Browser based web applications., to achieve this you have to use other third party jars:

- you would have to use Jacob library to connect to the COM
- [jagacy](https://dzone.com/articles/automated-acceptance-testing-for-mainframe-with-cu)
- A [3270 (Jagacy)](http://jameleon.sourceforge.net/jagacy-plugin/index.html) plug-in which is used to automate mainframe applications

Comment: Hi Sankalp, Any free source tools you can suggest? Jagacy 3270 comes with price

Comment: Actually this is best tools. I would know. as there are very less people who start automation in mainframe. This is the best answer I think. Please R& D more to find. Meanwhile you can accept as answer